# How can I loop through child nodes using Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json, razor

I'm trying to loop through some JSON data and print it to the screen. Here's what the JSON looks like:

[image: JSON data]

Using this code, I'm able to loop through the list of category names without any issues:

```
dynamic jsonObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

foreach (var obj in jsonObj.categories)
{
    <p> <strong> @obj.name </strong> </p>
}
```

I can't figure out how to loop through subcategories though. I tried this, but I just get Error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
foreach (var obj in jsonObj.categories)
{
    <p> <strong> @obj.name </strong> </p>

    foreach (var subcat in jsonObj.subcategories)
    {
        <p> <strong> @obj.name </strong> </p>
    }
}
```

Comment: you have a typo: in the second loop you should use `var subcat in obj.subcategories`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to get the subcategories from the parent object instead of the child one:

```
foreach (var category in jsonObj.categories)
{
    <p> <strong> @category.name </strong> </p>

    foreach (var subcategory in category.subcategories) // <= here is the key.
    {
         <p> <strong> @subcategory.name </strong> </p>
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, will be easier for you to follow the flow if you renamed "obj" to "category".

Answer (score 1):

You're calling subcategories on jsonObject, but you should call it on ojb.

Change your code to:

```
foreach (var subcat in obj.subcategories)
{
    <p> <strong> @obj.name </strong> </p>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (var obj in jsonObj.categories)
{
    <p> <strong> @obj.name </strong> </p>

    foreach (var subcat in obj.subcategories)
    {
        <p> <strong> @obj.name </strong> </p>
    }
}
```

You should loop into the `obj.subcategories`